# A matrix valued differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, matrix-equations

I am doing research in Quantum Field Theory and I ended up getting the following equation in the context of some gauge theory calculation:

$$\text{d}U=-U\cdot\Omega^\vee\cdot U,$$

where $U$ is an unknown $n\times n$ matrix (you can think about it as a change of basis matrix) and $\Omega^\vee$ is a ***known*** 1-form valued $n\times n$ matrix (can think of it as some connection matrix). I know that if $U$ was a vector (forgetting about the $U$ on the right most part of the equation) the solution would be a path-ordered exponential and that I know how to handle. But, with $U$ being a matrix, that seems to go beyond my current knowledge of differential equations.

I was wondering if the solution of such differential equation is known or well studied. I would really like some references if possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matrix Riccati differential equation.

Let $V = U^{-1}$, then $dV = -U^{-1} dU U^{-1} = Q^{\vee}$. You can take it from there.

Comment: Oh well, that was simple! Thanks a lot :)