# A matrix valued differential equation: Part 2

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

As a follow up to a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4215459/a-matrix-valued-differential-equation/4215467#4215467) I asked yesterday, the following type of differential equation also started to appear in some gauge theory calculations that I've been doing recently
$$\text{d}U=-(U\cdot\Omega^\vee_1+\Omega^\vee_2\cdot U).$$
Here, $U$ is a $n\times n$ matrix of functions (in many variables) I would like to ***solve for***, while both $\Omega^\vee_{1,2}$ are $n\times n$ matrices of 1-forms (in the same many variables) ***I already know*** from previous calculations.

Again, I would (ultimately) like to know if a general solution to such DE is known; so any tips from experts or references from the math/physics literature would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Unless I am missing something this is just a standard linear ODE?

Comment: Sure, but what I am asking for is if a closed form is known for this DE. For example, if $Y$ is a $n\times n$ matrix and satisfy the following differential equation

$$\text{d}Y=A\cdot Y,$$

and, although linear, the  solution to the DE has a particular closed form -- i.e.,

$$Y=\exp(\Omega)\cdot Y_0,$$

where $\Omega$ is found by solving $\text{d}\Omega=A-\frac{1}{2}[\Omega,A]+\frac{1}{12}[\Omega,[\Omega,A]]+...$ order by order (Magnus theorem). I am wondering if such an analogous theorem exists for the DE above.

Comment: Generalization from Magnus theorem to this particular DE seems non-trivial to me, so I asked.

Comment: I do not know about the Magnus theorem, but you can write the above in the form $Y' = AY$ for a suitable $Y$.

Comment: You mean with a linear transformation? If so, in general, $\text{d}U\to\text{d}Y:=\text{d}U+\text{some new crap}$, so I fail to see why you are sure about that $Y$ to exist. Could you elaborate more?

Comment: Find a basis for the $n \times n$ matrix and write the equation in terms of this basis.

Comment: After this comment, we should move this discussion to chat to avoid to much comments.

Ok, I see. But the thing is, in the context of my physical problem (I am generating the DEs for some master integrals corresponding to a particular family of Feynman diagrams), finding a "good basis" is a very hard thing (actually, an open problem). I want to study the solution $U$ of this particular DE for that precise reason: to understand better the link between a bad choice of basis (corresponding to $\Omega_1^\vee$) and a good one (corresponding to $\Omega_2^\vee$).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128189/discussion-between-davewashere-and-copper-hat).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the answer is easy to derive; I just tried the following natural ansatz and it worked

$$U(\textbf{s})=\left(\mathcal{P}\exp\int \Omega_2^\vee\right)\cdot U(\textbf{s}_0)\cdot\left(\mathcal{P}\exp\int \Omega_1^\vee\right),$$

where $\mathcal{P}$ stands for usual path-ordered exponential (one acting from the left and the other from the right) and where $\textbf{s}$ is the collection of active variables.